# dpkg error code (1) while trying to re-install Firefox

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation, firefox, dpkg

I removed Firefox by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
```

Then, I used Chrome browser for a while. Now, I want to re-install Firefox on my system, but I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  latex-xft-fonts firefox-gnome-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 49.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 452129 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking firefox (from .../firefox_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/plugins', which is also in package acroread 9.5.1-1precise1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to solve the problem by

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But that too generates a similar error. Would somebody please explain me the problem and its solution?

Comment: Maybe " which is also in package **acroread** 9.5.1-1precise1" is part of the problem?

Comment: It seems that this is a bug of the `acroread` package. It simply conflicts with Firefox on this: `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/` I suggest to get this into a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a conflict with the package "acroread". Where did you get this package from?

You could uninstall acroread:

```
sudo apt-get remove acroread
```

Then it should be possible to install Firefox again.

I just checked the latest version (9.5.3) from http://get.adobe.com/. This package doesn't seem to have the conflict, so you could re-install this package.

Another way would be to just overwrite the directories/files (there are dpkg-options...) or to delete/rename the directories/files before the installation of Firefox. But that's definitely not recommended...